# Visual studio shows Error while connecting to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2010

**Warning   3:**

> The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.12.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
>   be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly
>   "Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604" which was built against the
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than
>   the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".demo

Comment: The primary reference "MySql.Data..." could not be resolved **because** it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Google.Protobuf..." which was built against the **".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"** framework. This **is a higher version than** the currently targeted framework **".NETFramework,Version=v4.0..."**

Comment: nobody never reads exception messages

Comment: can you please tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: well, you may try to target framework **".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"**, so "MySql.Data..." could resolve all its indirect dependencies, just like exception message suggests:\

Answer (score 0):

Get a older Version
6.8.8 works out for me al the time